# I think I need looping

Tags: vba, excel

Very new to VBA, I have managed to create scripts that will generate and save/email pdfs. Thus far I have created a separate line for each change in the worksheet, for example:

```
Sheets("AM Dashboard").Select
Range("B5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Employee1"
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Google Drive\Sales Reports\Employee1\Sales Dashboard_Employee1" & " " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
Range("B5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Employee2"
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Google Drive\Sales Reports\Employee2\Sales Dashboard_Employee2" & " " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

What I would like to do is have the code loop through a list in sheet2 column A until the cell is empty and populate B5 of the AM Dashboard sheet with the respective value.

So for example, A1 would contain Employee1, A2 = Employee2, A3 = Employee3 etc.

Comment: Make a separate sub/function for generating the pdf's and call it within a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sheets("AM Dashboard").Select
Range("B5").Select

While (Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1) <> "")
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1)
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Google Drive\Sales Reports\Employee" & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1) & "\Sales Dashboard_Employee" & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1) & "" & " " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Comment: sh88 - thanks but it is giving me an error on the line - While (Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1) <> "") do I need to add a reference to the column which houses the values?  Thanks again

Comment: what error? is your worksheet named "Sheet2"? if not replace it with the right name. in which column in this sheet is the data youre looking for? then 1 in cells(i,1) stands for the first column. if its in another column you have to rplace the 1 with the correct column number

Comment: The error I am receiving is Runtime 1004.  Application-defined or object-defined error.  I have since renamed the sheet and adjusted the code but to no avail.

Comment: Figured it out... I needed to define i.  Thanks

Comment: Ok with `option explicit` you need `Dim i As Interger`